# "loadmore" type behavior when calling server side load function `+page.server.js` in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

I have a kind of obvious question but I am struggling with the answer.

I have a server side `+page.server.js` that needs to run serverside and does a bunch of queries to mongo and other apis. On my frontend `+page.svelte` show the results. simple enough…

Now I want to implement a `load more` button, and, eventually an infinite scroll.

For now, I used something like the below because I was in a rush. Adding the skip to the query to tell the load function what to load from the db,

```
<script>
function loadMore() {
        goto(`/search?query=${query}&skip=${skip}`, { noScroll: true });

}
</script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" on:click={loadMore}> Load More </button>
```

this is from `page.server.js`

```
export async function load({ params, url, setHeaders }) {
  const query = url.searchParams.get('query');

  if (!query) {
    return {}
  }

  const skip = url.searchParams.get('skip') ? url.searchParams.get('skip') : '0';
  const milvusResults = await search(query, MILVUS_NUM_RESULTS, skip);
  const idArray = milvusResults.map(milvusId => milvusId.id);
  const things = await findThings(idArray);

  return {
    things: thingsMerged,
    query: query,
    skip: parseInt(skip) + parseInt(MILVUS_NUM_RESULTS)
    // next:skip+MILVUS_NUM_RESULTS
  };

}
```

What would be much better if I didn’t need to use `skip`? It seemed like a throwback to 15 years ago when I wrote PHP. I don't want to have the `skip` parameter in the URL, for example, when you share the URL it would have the `...%skip=100`.

Can’t I call the load function on the server and pass the `skip` parameter without needing to send it in the URL? Here are the parameters I can send to the server-side load:

[SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#using-url-data)

There is the mention of a + page.js that can do that sort of thing and call a server-side method, but I can't figure it out:

```
+page.js:

// goto(`/search?query=${query}&skip=${skip}`, { noScroll: true });
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ fetch, params }) {
  //how do I pass the parameters query and skip? And can it co-exist with a server function of the same name? 
  const res = await fetch(`/search?query=${query}&skip=${skip}`);
  const item = await res.json();
  return {
    item
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, this is best done by:

- first move the main code into a function into a `+server.js` file.
- call this function from your load function in `+page.server.js`
- also call this function in a `loadMore` function, and replace `data` from sveltekit, something like this:

```
    async function getMoreImages() {
        // @ts-ignore
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams({ query: $page.data.query, skip: skip });
        const res = await fetch(`/api/search?${urlParams}`);
        return await res.json();
    }

    async function loadMore() {
        loading = true;
        const newData = await getMoreImages();
        data = newData;
        loading = !loading;
    }
```